# Yocto bitbake task for meta-raspberrypi fails with firmware download

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

I'm following an approach described in [JumpNow Technologies](http://www.jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html) to build a Yocto image for a Raspberry PI.  These steps utilize the Yocto meta-raspberrypi layer.

The bitbake process fails when doing a git fetch from `git://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git`.  The relevant part of the log is below.

```
bcm2835-bootfiles-20170303-r42 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git;protocol=git;branch=master, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: bcm2835-bootfiles-20170303-r42 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Unable to find revision 78bcdeae6bda4ecbc599af8c75e16c2ddd392d3a in branch master even from upstream
ERROR: bcm2835-bootfiles-20170303-r42 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git;protocol=git;branch=master'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
ERROR: bcm2835-bootfiles-20170303-r42 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
```

This step takes close to an hour or more. I'm assuming it's timing out somewhere and hence it fails.   This is happening because it's pulling down several GB.

I can fetch this repository manually separate to bitbake. Is there a way to insert the repo contents downloaded manually? e.g. into the downloads or tmp directly?

Alternatively, does anyone have a suggestion for dealing with this download?

Comment: It's not timing out, it's saying the specified revision does not exist in the repo. This seems to be a bug in the bbappends in jumpnows meta-rpi layer.

Comment: @jku - I confirmed with the owner of meta-rpi and he confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with meta-rpi as identified by @jku. I'm told jumpnow has fixed the issue.